# Derived invariant acyclic algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Call a connected quiver algebra $A=KQ/I$ (finite quiver Q and admissible ideal I) derived-invariant in case every quiver algebra derived equivalent to $A$ is even isomorphic to $A$.
For example local and preprojective algebras are derived invariant.

> Question: What are the derived invariant algebras with acyclic Q?

It seems to me that there are not really many, but I cant find an argument. The only examples I can think of are Q just a point and Q the Dynkin diagram $\mathcal{A_2}$ with $I=0$ (all hereditary algebras with at least 3 simple modules should  be not dervied invariant).

Thus the question:

> Is there an acyclic quiver algebra with at least 3 simples modules that is derived invariant?

Comment: Are you sure those are the only hereditary examples? Unless I'm misunderstanding something this is also true for n-Kronecker.

Comment: @GregStevenson Oops, you are probably right since an algebra derived equivalent to the n-Kronecker algebra should be again acyclic (?) with 2 simples so has to be a n-Kronecker algebra again.

Comment: Any basic tilting object would have to be a pair of consecutive transjectives (being the only rigids, consecutivity to avoid Ext's) and so have to give n-Kronecker again.

I am not sure if there's an argument that deduces it by first proving any derived equivalent algebra would have to be acyclic, but that would be amsuing.